# How can i use canGoBack() on GeckoView

Tags: android, firefox, webview, mozilla, geckoview

Below is the code for android Webview

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

How can i use similar code in Geckoview or how can i achieve similar process on Geckoview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeckoView provides this piece of information through [`NavigationDelegate.onCanGoBack`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.html#onCanGoBack-org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoSession-boolean-) but doesn't store it, so you need to create a class to do that that implements [`NavigationDelegate`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.html).

First create your own delegate class:

```java
private class MyNavigationDelegate implements GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate {
    public boolean canGoBack = false;

    @Override
    public void onCanGoBack(GeckoSession session, boolean canGoBack) {
        this.canGoBack = canGoBack;
    }
}

private MyNavigationDelegate navigationDelegate = new MyNavigationDelegate();
```

Then set the delegate somewhere where you create your `GeckoSession`:

```java
session.setNavigationDelegate(navigationDelegate);
```

And then you can implement `onBackPressed` like so:

```java
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (navigationDelegate.canGoBack) {
        session.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your answer to fix code errors.